# File storage service that allows clients to upload large files to my account?

Tags: storage, upload, services

Can anyone recommend an online file storage service which fulfills these requirements?

- I can create an account
- I can invite clients to upload files into my account
- clients do not need to register to be able to upload
- clients must not be able to see anything but their own files or they must not see any files at all, they get only a dropbox
- only I can access the uploaded files, everything is non-public
- service is multi-lingual

I just need clients to be able to send me potentially large files in a dead simple manner online, that's all. No registration step to go through, no software to download, no synching or sharing. No setting up of individual folders and permissions for each individual client. No copying and pasting of links (a la Mediafire, Rapidshare etc).

Comment: The best way to do it would be to use your own web hosting and set up your own self-run service.

Comment: It seems like I have to create my own service here, doesn't it? :-D

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard to set up a storage server with an internationalized web front end for blind uploads.  You could even develop it on top of Amazon S3 or Rackspace Cloud Files for the storage part.

Comment: Interestingly, that's exactly what I'm thinking about right now. :)

Answer (score 1):

[YouSendIt](http://www.yousendit.com/cms/compareaccounts) has a Business Plus version that sets up a dropbox-style page for people to upload files to you.  I haven't used it so I can't speak to whether it will meet your exact requirements.

Comment: Not bad, but I need it internationalized. English-only doesn't cut it unfortunately.